# Get record Id in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am looping through a list of records in a lightning component. I want to get the record Id for the selected checkbox record in the js controller.

```
<aura:iteration var="sw" items="{!v.swList}">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <div class="slds-truncate" >{!sw.contact.Name}</div>
        </td>
        <td >
            <div class="slds-truncate">{!sw.contact.Account__c}</div>
        </td>
        <td >
            <div class="slds-p-left_large">
                <lightning:input type="checkbox" checked="{!sw.contact.Optin__c}" onclick = "{!c.optIn}"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: is your id in your swList ? or some other attribute?

Comment: yes {!sw.contact.Id} is available in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your iteration, you might want to set the id to some attribute and use an onchange event handler, for example:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" checked="{!sw.contact.Optin__c}" value="{!sw.contact.Id}" onclick = "{!c.optIn}"/>
```

and use [event.getSource()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm).get('v.value') in the client-side controller to get the button components value that was triggered the onchange event

Comment: Thanks glls. I am switching to <ui:inputCheckbox> , can you please let me know how would I do the same with                                     <ui:inputCheckbox   value="{!sw.contact.Optin__c}" change = "{!c.optIn}"/>